# FFmpeg audio concat/join not work properly in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, audio, ffmpeg

I am concat/join audio using [ffmpeg_kit_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/ffmpeg_kit_flutter) with following command. But the joint file duration is not right.

```
"-i \"concat:${audioFile1}|${audioFile2}\" -acodec copy $outPath";
```

I have two audio files first audio file duration 27s and second audio file duration 1m 47s.

After join both files actual file duration is 2m 14s.

- But when we input 1st file in first input and 2nd file in second input then the output file duration is 2m 53s.
- And if we input 2nd file in first input and 1st file in second input then the output file duration is 2m 6s.

Following is my code:

```
var cmd = "-i \"concat:${audioFile2.path}|${audioFile1.path}\" -acodec copy $outPath";

FFmpegKit.executeAsync(cmd, (session) async {
      final returnCode = await session.getReturnCode();
      log("returnCode $returnCode");
    });
```

Please help me how to get the right duration after join both files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this command,

```
var cmd ="-i ${audioFile1.path} -i ${audioFile2.path} -filter_complex 'concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[a]' -map '[a]' -codec:a libmp3lame -qscale:a 2 $outPath";
```

Instead of

```
var cmd = "-i \"concat:${audioFile2.path}|${audioFile1.path}\" -acodec copy $outPath";
```